# how can i get this output use current array data

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i have current this array data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPLdd.png

and, i need this output in a loop

```
Array
(
    [post_title] => post 1
    [post_category] => 3
)

Array
(
    [post_title] => post 2
    [post_category] => 3
)
```

note: above image is example, to understand that this is a loop.

---

original output: surely, last array in loop.

```
Array
(
    [post_title] => post 2
    [post_category] => 3
)
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Tried using a `foreach`??. This is a pretty basic question. You need more tutorials to completely grasp an understanding of basic php

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over one of the child arrays and grab the sub-array key, add from all sub-arrays using that key

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'post 1',
        'post 2',
        'post 3'
    ),
    array(
        3,
        3,
        4
    )
);

$output = array();
foreach($arr[0] as $i => $element) {
    $output[] = array(
        $arr[0][$i],
        $arr[1][$i]
    );
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($output, true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Curious, what if `$arr[0]` is empty?

Comment: Then the foreach doesn't loop at all and you just get an empty array out. Just try it: https://ideone.com/u7RrgU

Comment: Then just add a check before iterating

Comment: Thanks for your help @Scoots

Comment: @Akintunde Why though? AFAIK `foreach`ing an empty array is no less efficient than wrapping the foreach in an `if` making sure it's not empty. Both would be equivilent to `$output = array();`

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    echo "[post_title] => ". $arr[0][$i];
    echo "[post_category] => ". $arr[1][$i];
}
```

Comment: A `foreach` would have been way easier though ;)and using `count` inside the forloop leads to a massive increase in time to complete. Just use `isset` or `empty`

Comment: You're counting the wrong array. Also, putting a `count` inside a for loop runs that count function for every single iteration of the loop - can lead to some massive run times if you have a lot of elements.

Comment: @in need of help you are so gorgeous, thanks very much man :)

Comment: but, this solution not effective for more than 2 array items.